# Best tool to use to "convert" Android apk into runnable web app(let)?

Tags: java, android, web, browser

I recently wrote a very simple apk app for a client - that runs nicely on their Android devices. They have since asked for it to be a runnable in web browser app (preferably phone and desktop). What would the best idea for this be?

As it's already in Java- perhaps a web applet? Are there any considerations here?
Or is there anything else that I can use? I've also heard to stay away from emulating the app within a web browser as it can be slow...

Sorry for asking a "unorthodox" question, but I know that SO people normally have a few suggestions that can put me on the right path...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would the best idea for this be?

Tell the client to go pound sand.

Or, rewrite the entire app in a hybrid app framework, such as Apache Cordova/PhoneGap, so your mobile and Web implementations are similar.

Or, rework your Android app to be a (small) pure-Java JAR of business logic, wrapped in an Android app. Then, implement a server-side Java Web app (e.g., WAR) that leverages that same JAR.

> perhaps a web applet?

Not all browsers support those, including roughly 0% of mobile browsers.

Comment: Thanks - I may just go the rewrite route...